# How to create multiple figures with subplots from a for loop where range is changing?

Tags: loops

I am trying to plot a figures which contains 5 rows and 1 column each with shared x. To plot each subplot in figure I am using for loop in range(). It works only for the first figure, but the next ones (fig3 and fig4) I get an error message: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

```
fig2, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, sharex=True)

for i in range(5): 
    
    axs[i].scatter(EvsRHE_a[i], FL_a[i], s=10, c='r', marker='>', label=i+1)
    axs[i].set_ylim(-5, 5)
    axs[i].legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=7)
    axs[i].set_xlim(0.8, 2.4)
    axs[i].set_xlabel(r"E [V vs RHE]", fontsize=10)
    
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()

fig3, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, sharex=True)

for i in range(5, 10): 
    
    axs[i].scatter(EvsRHE_a[i], FL_a[i], s=10, c='r', marker='>', label=i+1)
    axs[i].set_ylim(-5, 5)
    axs[i].legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=8)
    axs[i].set_xlim(0.8, 2.4)
    axs[i].set_xlabel(r"E [V vs RHE]", fontsize=10)
    
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()

fig4, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=1, sharex=True)

for i in range(10, 15): 
    
    axs[i].scatter(EvsRHE_a[i], FL_a[i], s=10, c='r', marker='>', label=i+1)
    axs[i].set_ylim(-5, 5)
    axs[i].legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=8)
    axs[i].set_xlim(0.8, 2.4)
    axs[i].set_xlabel(r"E [V vs RHE]", fontsize=10)
    
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()type here
```

any ideas how to solve it?